# Why "TTL (Time to live) is usually not a bad idea except when you are using write-through?"

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching

I heard somewhere that TTL is a good idea if you have sensible values that work for your workload the best, but it was said that it should not be used with write-through caching.

I can not think of any reasonable justification.

Comment: Because with a write-through cache, the cache data is never stale.  See [here](https://codeahoy.com/2017/08/11/caching-strategies-and-how-to-choose-the-right-one/#write-through-cache:~:text=next.-,Write%2DThrough%20Cache).

Comment: That makes sense, but it also makes sense that if you set TTL for write through you would have fewer superfluous data. And if you have lazy loading coupled with it, that would take care of reducing cache miss of un-updated data.

Comment: If you add lazy-loading to your write-through cache, it's no longer a pure write-through cache, which kind of invalidates the premise for your question :)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Robert Harvey's comment:

The point of a write-through cache is that every write request is routed through the cache in order to make sure the **data in the cache is always up to date**, i.e. has no stale data **and** there **won't be expensive [time] cache-misses**.

The trade off being, that you might have unused data in your cache and probably need a larger (and more expensive [money] cache node).

This trade off makes sense if you make sure that the cache holds all the data for queries, which a TTL on specific items would negate. While reducing cache size, you open yourself up to expensive [time] cache-misses.

Your proposal in the comment of going for a hybrid approach of adding TTL and lazy-loading to your cache wouldn't make it a purely write through cache that the recommendation refers to anymore so it doesn't necessarily apply.

Also you'd combine the write-penalty with the added complexity and risk of cache-misses which incur a read penalty. So you get the worst of both worlds in terms of time-expenses and complexity with the option of saving a little money on the cache node. You have to decide if that trade off is worth it for you.